# how many async calls can I make in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

<strike>In my application</strike>

```
int numberOfTimes = 1; //Or 100, or 100000

//Incorrect, please see update.
var tasks = Enumerable.Repeat(
                (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync("http://www.someurl.com")
            , numberOfTimes);

var resultArray = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

With numberOfTimes == 1, it takes 5 seconds.

With numberOfTimes == 100000, it still takes 5 seconds.

Thats amazing.

But does that mean I can run unlimited calls in parallel? There has to be some limit when this starts to queues?

What is that limit? Where is that set? What does it depend on?

In other words, How many IO completion ports are there? Who all are competing for them? Does IIS get its own set of IO completion port.

--This is in an ASP.Net MVC action, .Net 4.5.2, IIS

Update: Thanks to @Enigmativity, following is more relevant to the question

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfTimes ).Select(i => 
           (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync("http://deletewhenever.com/api/default"));

var resultArray = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

With numberOfTimes == 1, it takes 5 seconds.

With numberOfTimes == 100, it still takes 5 seconds.

I am seeing more believable numbers for higher counts now though. The question remains, what governs the number?

Comment: Are you sure you have 100000 tasks there and not just one? How many times do you call `GetStringAsync`?

Comment: It's only making the async call once, and then it repeats the value returned `n` times.

Comment: @labroo - How many times do you call that method? Your code is the same as `var task = (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync("http://www.someurl.com");` `var tasks = Enumerable.Repeat(task, numberOfTimes);` - you only have one `Task`, but you wait on it 100000 times.

Comment: Did you even look at _Task Manager_; _TcpView_; or monitor web server activity before posting this?

Comment: @Micky - That's a little harsh. This stuff is confusing. You have a good point though - I usually use side effects when I want to debug something like that.

Comment: Apologies, my bad. Updated the question. The question remains though. Although I am seeing more believable numbers for higher counts now.

Comment: Please don't modify a question to take it out of context with the answers. You can freely append though to ask a follow up.

Comment: @Kobi I probably was. ;)  I found it astounding that anyone would reach  the conclusion that 100000 calls takes the same as 1 and not think to check their experiment .  _"...it still takes 5 seconds. **Thats amazing**."_   The **original** post read as a statement of fact rather than a question

Comment: It was a silly mistake. I have apologized. And in my mistake, I sincerely was amazed. I have fixed it now. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: In essence with async IO you'll never run out of system resources in realistic cases. You'll saturate the network. "it still takes 5 seconds [for 100000 operations]" this is not true, measurement error. (Or, you were requesting a local URL that responds in <1ms which is contrived and means nothing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is that limit? Where is that set?

There's no explicit limit. However, you will eventually run out of resources. Mark Russinovich has an interesting [blog series on probing the limits of common resources](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx).

Asynchronous operations generally increase memory usage in exchange for responsiveness. So, each naturally-async op uses at least memory for its `Task`, an `OVERLAPPED` struct, and an IRP for the driver (each of these represents an in-progress asynchronous operation at different levels). At the lower levels, there are lots and lots of different limitations that can come into play to affect system resources (for an example, I have an old blog post where I [had to calculate the maximum size of an I/O buffer](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/03/io-limitation-in-windows.html) - something you would think is simple but is really not).

Socket operations require a client port, which are (in theory) limited to 64k connections to the same remote IP. Sockets also have their own more significant memory overhead, with both input and output buffers at the device level and in user space.

The IOCP doesn't come into play until the operations complete. On .NET, there's only one IOCP for your AppDomain. The default maximum number of I/O threads servicing this IOCP is 1000 on the modern (4.5) .NET framework. Note that this is a limit on how many operations may *complete* at a time, not how many may be *in progress* at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen. Is there a default for how many may be in progress at a time?

Comment: @labroo: No, you'll just run out of resources when you have too many.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test to see what's going on.

Start with this code:

```
var i = 0;
Func<int> generate = () =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return i++;
};
```

Now call this:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(generate(), 5)
```

After one second you get `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }`.

But make this call:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(n => generate())
```

After five seconds you get `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }`.

It's only calling the async function once in your code.

Comment: Apologies, my bad. Updated the question. The question remains though. Although I am seeing more believable numbers for higher counts now.

Comment: @labroo - You shouldn't change a question to take it out of context to existing answers. Please append any follow up questions.

Comment: @labroo I note you've dropped the number of iterations from 100000  to `100`

Comment: @labroo - You're still editing the original question that takes it out of context. I've edited in the way that an update should be done.

Comment: @Micky: Yes, as I said in my previous comment, I am seeing more believable numbers for higher counts now. I am still wondering what governs that number though.